# Unable to append text returned by ssh client in python

Tags: python, paramiko

Using paramiko module. I am trying to do ssh on remote systems. There I am executing a single command and need their output in the text file hcc.txt. Therefore I am creating a file object and saving the command o/p in the same text file.
1st Function is to write the o/p and 2nd is to append the o/p in existing text file hcc.
Somehow the append is not working.
import paramiko

```
usern = input("Enter your user name ")
passwd = input("Enter your password ")


def aa():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname='1.1.1.1',username=str(usern),password=str(passwd),port=22)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('finderr')
    x = str(stdout.read())
    fo = open("hcc.txt",'w')
    fo.write('aa' +x)
    fo.close()

def a():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname='2.2.2.2',username=str(usern),password=str(passwd),port=22)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('finderr')
    x = str(stdout.read())
    fo = open("hcc.txt",'a')
    fo.write('a' +x)

aa()
a()
```

O/p in file hcc.txt is "aab'There are no unfixed errors\n'"
I am expecting o/p like below

"aab'There are no unfixed errors\n'"
"ab'There are no unfixed errors\n'"

Comment: How about a context manager: `with open('hcc.txt', 'a') as fo: fo.write('a' + x)`

Comment: Warning

Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: with open('hcc.txt', 'a')  -- I am reopening the file in append mode and with fo.write('a' + x) I am expecting the command output in function(a) appended next to the first output returned in function(aa).

Comment: Of course but you're not closing it after.

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much. I got it fixed.

Comment: You're most welcome. Just use a context manager for any file operation in Python. That's the rule and what is expected unless you have a very good reason not to. It also improves the code quality because you have to group these operations in reasonably small blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the Python docs that applies to the code in your question:

> Warning
>
> Calling f.write() without using the with keyword or calling f.close() might result in the arguments of f.write() not being completely written to the disk, even if the program exits successfully.

So you should either call `fo.close` or use a context manager:

```
with open("hcc.txt",'a') as fo:
    fo.write('a' + x)
```